# Migrate AD onpremises to Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have two DCs onpremises that are only used for CRM dynamics 2016. So I need to migrate the CRM to AZURE

I think that first I have to migrate the DCs but hoy can I do it? I have to create a copy of them and then import them in Azure?

Also have ADFS

Any ideas? I dont know how to begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clean for, but you should start with Azure AD Connect https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594 in case, if you want to use Azure AD.
You you want to create VM with AD in Azure, you should create site-to-site VPN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal) and migrate all FSMO roles to Azure, after you can create new VM for CRM.

Comment: Hi, Oleg. I dont want to conserve any AD onpremises. I dont want to use Azure AD. I only need to have my two DC and two CRM vms in Azure. So I need to migrate AD and CRM

Comment: Got it, so build VNPs and use it.

Comment: sorry but I dont understand. What do you mean with VNPs? Thanks

Comment: you need to build a VPN between 2 networks (on-premises and Azure vNet) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal 
Then you create 2 VMs and attach them to your existing domain controller, after promote them to DC and migrate all FSMO roles. Then create 2 VMs for CRM and migrate it as well.

Comment: Its possible to shutdown the 4 virtual machines (2 DCs & 2 CRM servers) in VMWARE and import in Azure?